# Can I ask questions like "Who first used this technique in digital design?"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

history is a best teacher and expands the angle view of people.

Can I ask questions like "Who (how) first used this technique in digital design?"?

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb for if a question is on topic is this:

*If you're in a room with a professional designer, a computer engineer and a professional crafter, who would you ask your question?*

If the answer is 'the designer' than the question is *probably* on topic.

I would probably ask your example question to the designer. Even with a historian in the room, the designer would probably be able to give a better answer.

TLDR: ask away.